# Image not showing in Listbox ItemDataTemplate after MVVM conversion

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have some code that pulls data from a rest service and populates a listbox with Image and text using binding.

The original code was done in the mainpage code behind and an IValueConverter (returns a BitmapImage) is used for the image. All works fine.

I've ported this project to use the MVVM Light Toolkit in both WPF4 and Silverlight 4. WPF4 works as expected with the image and text being displayed however Silverlight 4 version fails to display the image and only shows the text.

With the MVVM port I've added mocking for designtime support. I've noticed that, in the Silverlight MVVM project, when i remove the iValueConverter in design time split view, the designtime image is displayed.

I've tried running the app with and without the iValueConverter but the image still doesn't show with no debug binding warnings. So I've checked that the binding works for the Image by binding the Image property to a Textblock and the full path URI displays in the Textblock.

I've also tried using the Mock service in (Silverlight) runtime and the image also doesn't display with/without the iValueConverter.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now solved. I started a new project, rebuilt it manually, compiled and worked. Same references & same code. Appears to be some Gremilin that got into one of the Microsoft internal files?!?